# Connect to .net DataServices using Monotouch?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, wcf-data-services

Is there any way to connect to Data Services using monotouch? creating a DataServices client an example would be really helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is avaible on monotouch it's under:

```
/Developer/MonoTouch/usr/lib/mono/2.1
```

I really don't know why it's not included on the stack, but you can reference it and it will work. Once imported into the project just use:

```
using System.Data.Services.Client;
```

I don't have an example, but it should work. :)

Comment: It is an oversight in our part.   The next update from MonoDevelop will list the assembly by default.